# Can I reuse React Context logic between packages in a monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I structure my code under a monorepo structure maintained with yarn workspaces. Looks roughly like this:

```
packages/
  react-hooks/
    foo-app/
    bar-app/
```

Both `foo-app` and `bar-app` are React projects created with CRA. I moved my Hooks in the `react-hooks` package so I don't duplicate code.

Most of the Hooks still work fine, but a few of them rely on some application-wide context state. Specifically, [web3-react](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react)'s `useWeb3Context` Hook.

The `react-hooks` package gets transpiled with babel, which has this config:

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/env"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"],
};
```

Is there any way to reuse the context logic between packages, or should I resort to passing the values as parameters to my Hooks?

Comment: Honestly I think it's a bad React programming practice to try to re-use application specific context across multiple independent apps.

Comment: Packages within yarn workspaces are much closer to each other than in traditional monorepo structures.

Comment: @Rawrplus why it is a bad idea, and what is better to share code between 2 app of the same project (example "web app" and "dashboard" ) ?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @Ziarno yes, if I recall correctly, the problem was that I was not using the exact same `react` and `react-dom` versions. It has to be the same everywhere.